# Как правильно подключить Susy?

Tags: css, sass

Как правильно подключить **Susy**, если я использую **gulp**, и **sass** уже установлен.

Я пытаюсь подключить следующим образом:

```
@import "node_modules/susy/sass/_susy.scss";
```

Но если так подключать, то не работает **clearfix;** например, не находит его.
А если использовать `@include span(6);` ,то `span(6)`; работает. 
Так как же все таки правильно подключить  **Susy**?

Comment: Я пока точно не уверен, но пхоже нужно было использовать susy-clearfix;

Comment: Я пока оставлю [это](https://github.com/lacroixdesign/node-bourbon/blob/master/README.md#gulpjs-usage) здесь и как доберусь до компьютера, объясню, если вы не догадаетесь.

Comment: @D-side - пока не догадался, но еще посмотрю, только чуть позже.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно подсказать Sass'у **"include paths"**, места, в которых ожидаются файлы дополнительных библиотек, чтобы импорт был максимально тупым, ни на что не рассчитывал и легко переносился на любую сносную систему сборки (хоть в тот же Compass). Импорт такого вида:

```
@import "susy";
```

Это импортирует файл `_susy.scss` или `_susy.sass` из текущей папки **или "include paths"**.

И тут начинаются довольно весёлые проблемы. Разные библиотеки по-разному публикуют пути к своим файлам. Но в итоге в `gulpfile.js` должна получиться конструкция такого вида:

```
sass({
  includePaths: [путь] // здесь должны быть перечислены пути к используемым библиотекам
})
```

Осталось найти `путь`. Бывают хорошие люди, которые [экспортируют пути в точке входа<sup>*</sup>](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/index.js), но авторы Susy в качестве точки входа указали SCSS-файл. Довольно загадочный ход, но можно получить путь к нему и отрезать имя файла, оставив только папку:

```
path = require('path')
susy_main = require.resolve('susy') // получение абсолютного пути к точке входа susy
susy_dir  = path.dirname(susy_main) // путь, полный, с точкой входа, но нужна только папка
```

Всё, нужный путь (абсолютный!) лежит в `susy_dir`.

---

<sup>* Модули в NodeJS обычно пакуются в одноимённые папки, и когда делается `require(название)`, возвращается объект, который экспортирует его **точка входа**: файл, указанный в `package.json` под ключом `"main"` (а если этого ключа нет, он попытается угадать, [см. инструкцию](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)). Следуя примеру по ссылке выше, [вот указание точки входа в *Bourbon*](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/888e83a9f90a5d7d795e5ffa3ad035743a8d1393/package.json#L23).</sup>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34298/discussion-on-answer-by-d-side----susy).